# Como puedo capturar el número de error en Java

Tags: java, java-swing

espero que me puedan orientar ya que,tengo este codigo en C# pero lo tengo que pasar a java me doy cuenta que ciertas palabras como **" ErrorCode, Win32Exception, as, Win32Exception y Var"** no las reconoce java, me pueden ayudar a estructurar este codigo en java o bien orientarme,de la manera que se hace en JAVA por favor

```
var Mesaje = e as Win32Exception;
            if (Mesaje == null)
            {
                Mesaje = e.InnerException as Win32Exception;

            }
            if (Mesaje != null)
            {
                 int Error = Mesaje.ErrorCode;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

En Java, la forma de controlar los errores en tiempo de ejecución es mediante el control de excepciones.
Creo que Java como tal no devuelve el código de error, pero sí el mensaje de error.
Para obtener el mensaje, puedes utilizar un bloque **try-catch** y en el **catch**, a través del objeto de tipo **Exception**, puedes utilizar el método **e.getMessage()** para obtener el mensaje con el motivo del error.

```
try {
    //Aquí va el código que puede producir el error
} catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Si resuelve tu duda, por favor marca como respondida :) !Un saludo!